# Saving and retrieving PDF to and from SQLite in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I have saved and retrieved IMAGE in sqlite, i want to do the same for PDF(which i have as local file)...

```
- (void)saveImage 
{
  sqlite3_stmt *compiledStmt;
  sqlite3 *db;
  if(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db)==SQLITE_OK){
  NSString *insertSQL=@"insert into Image(image) VALUES(?)";
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db,[insertSQL cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], -1, &compiledStmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
     {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"vegextra.png"];
        NSData *imageData=UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

        sqlite3_bind_blob(compiledStmt, 1, [imageData bytes], [imageData length], SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

           if(sqlite3_step(compiledStmt) != SQLITE_DONE ) {
                  NSLog( @"Error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db) );
            } else {
                  NSLog( @"Insert into row id = %lld",  (sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(db)));
            }

       sqlite3_finalize(compiledStmt);
     }
   }
     sqlite3_close(db);
   }

  - (void)showImage
   {
       sqlite3_stmt *compiledStmt;
       sqlite3 *db;
       int i = 1;
         if(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db)==SQLITE_OK)
         {
           NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Select image from Image Where Id = %d",i];
         if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db,[insertSQL cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], -1, &compiledStmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) 
          {
             while(sqlite3_step(compiledStmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {

             int length = sqlite3_column_bytes(compiledStmt, 0);
             NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(compiledStmt, 0) length:length];

             NSLog(@"Length : %d", [imageData length]);

                if(imageData == nil)
                       NSLog(@"No image found.");
                else
                       imgView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        }
       }
       sqlite3_finalize(compiledStmt);
      }
        sqlite3_close(db);
   }
```

HERE I need to store and retrieve **PDF** as same as image.

Answer (score 0):

It's identical. Load the PDF into an `NSData` object. Once you have the `NSData`, it's the same as your image data.

Actually, in both cases (PDF and image), you should do the same thing. Get the full path to the file and load the file directly into `NSData`. For the image, there is no reason to create the `UIImage` first.

Having said all of that, why are you putting all of that data in the database? Why not just keep the files in the filesystem? If anything, store the filename in the database. Keeping the files as actual files is much more efficient than storing them as blobs in the database.

Comment: How is "keep the files in the filesystem" comparing to the new core data "Store in External Record File" feature?

Comment: Actually, storing the data in the database [is more efficient if the files are smaller than about 100 KB](http://www.sqlite.org/intern-v-extern-blob.html).